# python change bash directory mac

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.6

Everyday When i open my mac.

I open bash and execute the following commands :

```
cd desktop 
cd reference
cd django
cd mel
cd python3 manage.py runseerver
```

I want to make the above process automated, where If i run one python script all the above should be executed in the shell.

When I have tried so far :

```
import os
wd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir("desktop")
```

The above doesn't give me any error nor does it changes the directory

Comment: It _does_ change the directory—but only for the Python script and any child processes that it runs, not for the parent process. There is no way to change the directory for a parent process on macOS (or any other modern OS). But that's OK; you can just do all of the commands inside this Python script: four `os.chdir` calls, then one `subprocess.run` call.

Comment: While we're at it, you don't need four separate `cd` (or `os.chdir`) commands, you can just `cd desktop/reference/django/mel`.

Comment: Even better: you can create a Terminal Profile whose starting directory is `/Users/Learning Django/desktop/reference/django/mel`, and optionally make it run `python3 manage,py runseerver` as its command instead of `bash`. (I don't remember exactly how to do all of this with the built-in Terminal, because I used iTerm2, which makes it easier… but I'm pretty sure it's possible with Terminal too.)

Comment: Or, even better… do you need this to be in a terminal window in the first place? If not, create a LaunchAgent or Launch Item that just runs this automatically at login.

Comment: You know you can do: ``python3 desktop/reference/django/mel/manage.py runserver``. It should still work correctly even if you aren't in that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set aliases in your `.bashrc` file. Open your `.bashrc` file with `nano` or `vim` and append the following.

`alias run_mel='cd desktop/reference/django/mel/python3 && manage.py runserver'`

Save and exit the file after adding the alias then run `source .bashrc`

You should then be able to start your server from the home directory by only running `run_mel`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could write a single command that can be executed once and it does the whole job.

`cd desktop/reference/django/mel && python3 manage.py runserver`

This is not a python script, but you can achieve what you want easily with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it all in one cmd

```
os.system("cd desktop && cd reference && cd django && cd mel && python3 manage.py runserver")
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your python script should look like this:

```
import os 
os.system(python3 desktop/reference/django/mel/manage.py runserver)
```